# IOS UITableView display first 5 rows of an array

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, cell, blur

I have a UITableView with 1 cell and when the array loads I just want for the user to see the content of the first 5 rows and blur the rest. So, if there is an array with 20 items, the first 5 need to be visible and the remaining 15 with a blur. With the code below, I'm able to just add a blur to row 5 only, I can't figure this out. Any help is greatly appreciated.

**ViewController**

```
let visualEffectView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: UIBlurEffect(style: .light))



    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return array.count
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! CustomTableViewCell
        cell.cellLbl?.text = array[indexPath.row]

        if indexPath.row == 5 {
            visualEffectView.frame = cell.bounds
            visualEffectView.layer.masksToBounds = true
            cell.addSubview(visualEffectView)
        }
        return cell
    }
```

[image]

Comment: instead of "if indexPath.row == 5", have you try "if indexPath.row > 5"  ??

Comment: It does not work, it only blurs 1 row and when I scroll down, the blur appears on the last row.

Comment: Ohh I understand, but maybe you can provide us some screenshots or even better a GIF

Comment: screenshot added.

Comment: Great. See my answer in the answer section :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't share a single visual effect view which you move between cells. (A view can only exist once in thew view hierarchy. If you add it as a subview in 2 places, it gets removed from the first place).

Your code should also use `if indexPath.row >= 5`, not `if indexPath.row == 5`

I would suggest creating a custom subclass of UICollectionViewCell that has a public blurView `IBOutlet`. Install a blur view in the cell in your XIB/storyboard. In your `tableView(_:cellForRowAt:)` method, hide the blur view if the row is < 5, else un-hide it.

Comment: made sense and i was able to accomplish what I was looking for. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Because you are trying to add a single visualEffectView variable to multiple cell. Try to fix your **cellForRowAt** method like this:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! CustomTableViewCell
    cell.cellLbl?.text = array[indexPath.row]
    
    if indexPath.row >= 5 {
      let visualEffectView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: UIBlurEffect(style: .light))
      visualEffectView.frame = cell.bounds
      visualEffectView.layer.masksToBounds = true
      cell.addSubview(visualEffectView)
    }
    return cell
  }
```

Comment: Thank you, this does hide the remaining rows but when I scroll down and then back up the blur covers everything.

Comment: Hmm this is strange, I even try my code before posting here and it works :((

Comment: Working for me....

Answer (score 0):

This is happening for a number of reasons.

1. You seem to allocate a single blur view instance in your view controller. This doesn't make sense because you need N blur views since you want to add a blur view to each row >= 5.
2. Even if you had multiple blur view instances, your logic specifically checks to see if `indexPath.row == 5`. You would want it to be `indexPath.row >= 5`.

To fix this, I'd recommend the following:

1. Add a blurView property to `CustomTableViewCell`. This will ensure every cell will have its own blur view instance. Make sure this blur view is added as the top-most subview of the content view and covers the entire content view. Make sure this subview is hidden by default.
2. In `CustomTableViewCell`, override `prepareForReuse` and set `blurView.isHidden = true`
3. In your `tableView(_:cellForRowAt:)` method, set `cell.blurView.isHidden = indexPath.row >= 5`